# Prevent sending mail to "Promotions" in gmail

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, email-spam, promotions

I am using **Amazon Simple Email Service** to send email to my web application users. I am sending mail by using verified email by amazon as well but still, emails are being sent on *Promotions* tabs in Gmail.

Anyone can guide me for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

If your mail appears to be promotional in nature, then it belongs in the Promotions tab, and that is where Gmail will present it unless a preponderance of your recipients are engaging with it in such a way as to indicate it belongs in a different tab.

Generally speaking, important and one-to-one correspondence will be presented in the Primary tab, social media in the Social tab, news alerts, newsletters, transactional mail will display in the Updates tab, and list traffic in the Forums tab.

Mail displaying in any of these tabs are, by definition, in the Gmail inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is al old question, but I found this excellent resource, I though it will be good to share. Follow these steps you should be out of trouble (and out of the Promotions folder, too)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/tips-and-best-practices.html